# How to cancel a call to dispatch_after?

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, cancellation

I'm making an application where two buttons are moving. The first moves immediately and the second one moves after 1 second. What's happening now in my application is that when I click the start button before one second has passed, it shows two of the second button moving. I believe what I would have to do is that when the button is clicked, I would have to cancel the `dispatch_after`, but when I try to do this by writing this code:

```
let time1 = dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW),1 * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC))
dispatch_after(time1, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    // code of second button moving
}
if time1 == true
    {time1 = false}
```

it says that I cannot assign this to a `dispatch_time`. What should I do?
This is the complete code if this helps you:

```
@IBAction func startbutton(sender: UIButton) {
// code for moving the first button
let time1 = dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW),1 * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC))
dispatch_after(time1, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    // code of second button moving
}
if time1 == true
    {time1 = false}
}
```

Comment: A `dispatch_time` is not a boolean, so you can't compare it to `true` or `false` or assign those values to it. Perhaps more importantly, how are you animating these buttons? UIKit animations don't normally require GCD calls.

Comment: Ok I will update the question.